# How to recreate nginx's try_files in Play Framework for hosting React site

Tags: java, scala, reactjs, playframework, playframework-2.6

I am trying to host a React site from a Play Framework server. The React front-end is developed in a separate project and its build artifacts (static html/js/css/etc. files) are copied into my Play project's `public` folder.

Now I tried navigating to e.g. /page1 (where that's a React route), but I get a 404 because of course the server does not have such a route.

What I want is to replicate nginx's `try_files $uri /index.html` kind of functionality - if the path that's being asked for can be served (i.e. it corresponds to an asset the server knows about), it is served. Else, serve the contents of index.html *without* rewriting the url, so that React's routing can work.

I've tried getting this to work with just the `routes` file and also as a controller (with an if/else). I haven't been able to exactly replicate what in nginx is a one-liner. How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @vdebergue says, you can get a simplified version of what you want by adding a catch-all at the *bottom* of your `conf/routes` file.

**However** if you have *other* files in `public` that you'd like to still be served up correctly (for example, image files), you need to use something a little more powerful.

I wrote about this in [my blog in July](http://blog.themillhousegroup.com/2017/07/the-crap-stack-part-3-front-end-routes.html), but as per Stack Overflow convention, I'll expand upon it here as well. Basically, you can copy [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/themillhousegroup/11304501695a2c0ca4c2a91adeaea63b), which declares a `FrontEndServingController`.

The key functionality that this controller gives above the built-in `Assets` controller is that on first use, it recursively scans your `public` directory to find *real* files, so it knows when to serve them up, and when to serve up `index.html` (your React app).

Then you use it in your `routes` file like this:

```
GET /       controllers.FrontEndServingController.index
GET /*file  controllers.FrontEndServingController.frontEndPath(file)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly in "dev mode", but failed in prod mode. Specifically, it appears that you cannot use `f.listFiles` on line 25 of your Gist, it blows up with a `NullPointerException`.

I had to modify the Gist as follows in order to get it to work for both dev and prod modes: https://gist.github.com/mrubin/211f007508cd90f471d697132727808c

Comment: Note that you could get rid of the explicit `index` route if you wanted to, if you rewrote the route as follows:

`GET /$path<.*>       controllers.FrontEndServingController.frontEndPath(path)`

Comment: Thanks for the contributions and suggestions @iraxef!

Answer (score -1):

You can do it simply in the route file. At the bottom of the file, add this catch all rule:

```
# your other routes above
# ...
GET     /$any<.*>                controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="index.html")
```

Comment: This does not work:

`Compilation error[Missing parameter in call definition: any]
[error] GET     /$any<.*>                controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="index.html")`